# Connect to SSH using password and Perform Some commands using shell script?

Tags: php, git, ssh, sh, magento2

I am working on Magento 2 Project.

I did Setup Git on my server. so I can push and pull changes on server directly without using ftp.

in my local i do push changes to git. and I do pull on remote side. so I get my changes over there.

So I am thinking to create shell script that manually written command are perform one by one by just executing one script.

In Script I am thinking too.

- Connect server using ssh. hosts name and password.
- and then enter in project directory using cd project name.
- and there it perform git pull command.
- and some magento commands to update changes. (Like: bin/magento setup:upgrade etc...)

So is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: Perhaps sshpass would be of use

Comment: @Joeri What is sshpass I am not aware of that. it's the tool or something? I am using Ubuntu Operating System. so sshpass will work on ubuntu?

Comment: Sshpass is a tool that "types" a password into the password input for you. You will have to store it in plain text (afaik) so I'd only use it if key-based authentication is not available EDIT: sshpass https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib. A good library for secure connections via php

Comment: Ok Let's I try @Joeri

Comment: Have you had success @Bhautik Jethva ?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute commands over ssh by doing `ssh user@host 'command1;command2'` and either use sshpass (but you'd have to store the password in plain text, which is a bit of a no no) or set up key-based authentication (recommended)

Answer (score 0):

First, you’ll have to install sshpass, can install by running following command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install sshpass
```

Now go to /home/{youruser}/ and open .bashrc file in any editor ( Press Ctrl+H, if file not visible ).

Now let’s create a command alias, create a new line in .bashrc file as per your project details. For example:

```
alias connect-magentto=’sshpass -p “your ssh password here” ssh yourusername@yourhostname’
```

Copy-paste above command in .bashrc file and save it and open a new terminal. Enter “connect-magento” in the terminal and now you’ll connect to the server without a copy, pasting, or typing anything.

Similarly, you can make shortcut of other commands whichever you wish to by adding in .bashrc file and giving it an alias.